# dialog works first time only

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the following java script code

```
      function showDialog() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen : true, height : '325', width : 'auto', modal : true, closeOnEscape : false,

        });
        $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'title', "Manage Questions");
        $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'show', 'drop');
        $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'resizable', true)
        var strHtml = <MyCode>;
        $("#dialog").html(strHtml);
        $("#dialog").html();
        $("#dialog").dialog('open');
        }
```

when I call showDialog first time it works fine. but after that
when user click on button that calls this function, the dialog appears then automatically disappear, if user clicks again it works fine, 
in other words
    First time it works fine, then user have to click twice to make it work.

Comment: where did you put that function ? is it under document ready function? or outside?

Comment: outside the ready function

Comment: can you try to reproduce the problem in jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce it: http://jsfiddle.net/0rkxs1u2/

Please update your question with a jsfiddle showing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have not added any button for closing dialog, please add below code for closing dialog first and then open it.

```
 $("#dialog").dialog("close");
```

your code should be like below

```
function showDialog() {
        //close dialog
        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen : true, height : '325', width : 'auto', modal : true, closeOnEscape : false,

        });
        $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'title', "Manage Questions");
        $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'show', 'drop');
        $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'resizable', true)
        var strHtml = <MyCode>;
        $("#dialog").html(strHtml);
        $("#dialog").html();
        $("#dialog").dialog('open');
        }
```

Comment: i DID, THERE IS A BUTTON INSIDE THE DIALOG HTML THAT CLOSE THE DIALOG